# MEX-file implementing Eigen library pseudo-inverse function crashes

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, mex

I am trying to implement an Eigen library pseudo-inverse function in a Matlab MEX-file.  It compiles successfully but crashes when I run it.

I am trying to follow [the FAQ on how to implement a pseudo-inverse function using the Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Is_there_a_method_to_compute_the_.28Moore-Penrose.29_pseudo_inverse_.3F).

The FAQ suggests adding it as a method to the `JacobiSVD` class but since you can't do that in C++ I'm adding it to a child class.  It compiles successfully but then crashes without an error message.  It successfully outputs "hi" without crashing if I comment out the line with the `.pinv` call so that's where the problem is arising.  To run, I just compile it (as `test.cpp`) and then type `test` at the command line.  I am using Matlab R2019a under MacOS 10.14.5 and Eigen 3.3.7.  In my full code I also get lots of weird error messages regarding the `pinv` code but before I can troubleshoot I need this simple test case to work.  This is all at the far limits of my understanding of C++.  Any help appreciated.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804402/add-a-method-to-existing-c-class-in-other-file
class JacobiSVDext : public JacobiSVD<MatrixXf> {
    typedef SVDBase<JacobiSVD<MatrixXf>> Base;
    public:
    using JacobiSVD::JacobiSVD; //inherit constructors //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors
    MatrixXf pinv() //http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ
    {
        eigen_assert(m_isInitialized && "SVD is not initialized.");
        double  pinvtoler=1.e-6; // choose your tolerance wisely!
        JacobiSVDext::SingularValuesType singularValues_inv=m_singularValues;
        for ( long i=0; i<m_workMatrix.cols(); ++i) {
            if ( m_singularValues(i) > pinvtoler )
                singularValues_inv(i)=1.0/m_singularValues(i);
            else singularValues_inv(i)=0;
        }
        return m_matrixV*singularValues_inv.asDiagonal()*m_matrixU.transpose();
    };
};

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    MatrixXf X = MatrixXf::Random(5, 5);
    JacobiSVDext svd(X);
    MatrixXf Y=svd.pinv();
    cout << Y << endl;
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

The expected result is to output the pseudo-inverse of the random matrix and also "hi".  Instead it crashes without an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing the `Eigen::JacobiSVD` object, you fail to request that matrices U and V should be computed. By default, these are not computed. Obviously, accessing these matrices if they are not computed will cause a segmentation violation.

See [the documentation to the constructor](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html#abfd1dd454a6e3edec7feecd97c818a78). A second input argument must specify either `ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV`, or `ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV`. The thin ones are preferable when computing the pseudo-inverse, as the rest of the matrices are not needed.

---

I would not derive from the `JacobiSVD` class just to add a method. Instead, I would simply write a free function. This is both easier, and allows you to use only the documented portions of the Eigen API.

I wrote the following MEX-file, which works as intended (using code I already had for this computation). It does the same, but in a slightly different way that avoids writing an explicit loop. Not sure this way of writing it is very clear, but it works.

```cpp
// Compile with:
//    mex -v test.cpp -I/usr/local/include/eigen3

#include "mex.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

Eigen::MatrixXf PseudoInverse(Eigen::MatrixXf matrix) {
   Eigen::JacobiSVD< Eigen::MatrixXf > svd( matrix, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV );
   float tolerance = 1.0e-6f * float(std::max(matrix.rows(), matrix.cols())) * svd.singularValues().array().abs()(0);
   return svd.matrixV()
         * (svd.singularValues().array().abs() > tolerance).select(svd.singularValues().array().inverse(), 0).matrix().asDiagonal()
         * svd.matrixU().adjoint();
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf X = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(5, 5);
    Eigen::MatrixXf Y = PseudoInverse(X);
    std::cout << Y << '\n';
    std::cout << "hi\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  This code seems to provide the same results as Matlab's pinv function, which is what I needed.